# How to mask IP in AWS cloud watch in AWS ELB via AWS cli by custom header?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, amazon-elb

Is there any way to configure AWS loadbalancer via `AWS cli` to put predefine text like **na** in place of `IP`?

**Example data log**

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/access-log-collection.html#access-log-entry-examples

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not sure why you would like to do. The whole purpose of access log is to see from where the traffic is coming from. Which will not be relevant if you replace the IP address with NA.

So, the simple thing is to disable the whole logs. But I think you need the log as well without the IP, may be due to some audit purpose or anything. For that you need to get the logs and edit it by a script. I don't think you can have a predefined way that `AWS` do not log the IP as it is the main purpose for those logs.

hope this helps.

cheers

Comment: this is as per requirement of GDPR in EU.

Comment: aah i thought so too.. so in that scenario you have to disable the logging. The current project i am working on is in EU with GDPR thingy. The law suggests youo should not capture it altogether and here if you capture and delete it.. it is  still against GDPR.

Comment: Thank you for your though, I think, I need to enable custom access log in web server, an need to disable in Loadbalancer, as AWS support team had not repiyed on support ticket.

Comment: No problm.. AWS support is a bit slow to respond even if you are a  Private Cloud owner with premium support. :)

Comment: If this answer is useful, please consider to tick it as answer. thanks

Comment: AWS support team given list of aws cli commands, from the ocean of reference URLs, I need dig  more from it. Thank you for thought but it did not solved my problem.